# C++ :: Boost :: AccessViolationException for no reason (VS13)

Tags: c++, boost

Yesterday I installed some Visual C++ redist packages. Today I tried to start my project, and encountered "vshost.exe stopped working" during project initialization. I uninstalled theese packages and recovered/restored Windows to the point before package installation, but it didn't help. By enabling native code debugging, I was able to see that exception is thrown at

```
void release()
{
    if( BOOST_SP_INTERLOCKED_DECREMENT( &use_count_ ) == 0 )   //Here
    {
        dispose();
        weak_release();
    }
}
```

> Exception is "Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCD04".

Windows 7

Visual Studio 2013

How should this be handled?
Can reinstalling all VC++ packages help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the problem solved by rebuilding under release and then back under debug